# How to initialise a multi-dimensional MLMultiArray

Tags: swift, machine-learning, coreml, onnx, coremltools

I'm hosting a CoreML model that takes a `MLMultiArray` of rank 4 as its input:

[image]

My input data is as follows:

```swift
let inputArray: [[[Float]]]
```

But I can't figure out how to initialise the MLMultiArray from it. Here are some attempts:

```swift
MLMultiArray(inputArray) // error: No exact matches in call to initializer
```

```swift
let multiArray = try! MLMultiArray(shape: [0, 128, 128, 1], dataType: .float32)
multiArray[0,1] = inputArray[0] // Cannot assign value of type '[[Float]]' to subscript of type 'NSNumber'
```

```swift
memset(multiArray.dataPointer, 0, 128*128) // EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
```

How do you initialise such a MLMultiArray?

Answer (score 1):

Initialising it as

```swift
let input = try! MLMultiArray(shape: [1, 128, 128, 1], dataType: .float64)
```

is correct (note that I edited the input shape in coremltools).

The populating should be as follows:

```swift
for batchIndex in 0..<inputArray.count {
    for heightIndex in 0..<inputArray[0].count {
        for widthIndex in 0..<inputArray[0][0].count {
            input[[batchIndex, heightIndex, widthIndex, 0] as [NSNumber]] = (inputArray[batchIndex][heightIndex][widthIndex]) as NSNumber
        }
    }
}
```